# bash script to tcl script converter

Tags: tcl

I am very new to TCL. I want a converter to convert bash to TCL. Do you know of a converter that will convert a bash script to a TCL script?

Comment: I don't know of any such thing. I doubt one exists. Please continue to post specific questions. It sounds like you might benefit from the TclTutor (http://www.msen.com/~clif/TclTutor.html)

Comment: ok. I also search the translater but i am not getting. Its ok.

Answer (score 3):

Translating one programming language into another is in general an ultra-difficult task, because establishing equivalence between two programs is mathematically highly challenging. The only exception is when someone's *defined* the source language by translation into the target (not the case with Tcl and Bash, whichever way you're looking to do translation!) It's even harder to take idiomatic programs in one language and convert into idiomatic programs in another; idioms *don't* transfer simply.

That said, it's possible to make some progress with translating specific programs from Bash to Tcl as there's a fair overlap in capabilities. But it's not on a basis of mechanical conversion; it's by hand (and mind, of course).
If the script is pretty short, an easy way to make some progress is to ask here on SO while showing the script. (If it has passwords in, replace those before showing.)